# How to use asyncio create_connection for IPv6 addresses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-asyncio

In my code I've tried using asyncio create_connection to connect to get clients to connect to a TCP server.  For some reason, the connection is successful when I try use an IPv4 address:

```
event_loop.create_connection(client_factory, host='127.0.0.1', port=8190)
```

But the connection fails when I use an IPv6 address:

```
event_loop.create_connection(client_factory, host='::1', port=8190)
```

When I use the IPv6 loopback address, I get an OSError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<removed>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 778, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "C:\Users\<removed>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 765, in create_connection
    yield from self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "C:\Users\<removed>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 451, in sock_connect
    return self._proactor.connect(sock, address)
  File "C:\Users\<removed>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 511, in connect
    ov.ConnectEx(conn.fileno(), address)
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

Looking at the documentation, it looks like the `family` parameter for create_connection defaults to `socket.AF_UNSPEC`.  I also tried the same call by specifying the family:

```
event_loop.create_connection(client_factory, host='::1', port=8190, family=socket.AF_INET6)
```

But I get the same result.  I know setting host to `'localhost'` will work for this example, but I want to know how to use any IPv6 address for `create_connection`.